# How track element id in a single line of code instead of having multiple script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to track multiple buttons on a page, and I manage to do it with this current code by copy-pasting it multiple times, but I would like to shorten it. However, I can't figure out how I can do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var button = document.getElementById('lp-pom-button-201');
  button.addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function() { 
      fbq('track', 'click to call', {
        tracking_number: 'Phone Number',
      });          
    },
    false
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show a little bit of the HTML code, I am a little confused about the problem, whether it is a single button(Which shouldn't give you this problem, or multiple buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **callback** instead of recreating the function each time
You can achieve it this way:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var button = document.getElementById('lp-pom-button-201');
  
  function myCallback() { 
      fbq('track', 'click to call', {
        tracking_number: 'Phone Number',
      });          
    }
  
  button.addEventListener('click', myCallback, false);
</script>
```

By this way you have only to bind the Event to a a button and centralized the management of it inside a single function.

More on callback: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 1):

[Patrissol Kenfack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59743760/5144579) answer certainly would be better than repeating the same function over and over.

To expand on his answer, you might consider using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

Example:

```js
function myCallback() {
  console.log(this.dataset.tracking)
}

document.querySelectorAll('[bind-onclick]').forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', myCallback, false);
})
```

```html
<div bind-onclick data-tracking="1">Click One</div>
<div bind-onclick data-tracking="2">Click Two</div>
<div bind-onclick data-tracking="3">Click Three</div>
```

All that said, you're appear to be using buttons (like you should; unlike I did above). Probably, should just use the `onclick` attribute instead of event listeners.

```js
function buttonClicked(el) {
  console.log(el.dataset.tracking)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonClicked(this)" data-tracking="1">Click One</button>
<button onclick="buttonClicked(this)" data-tracking="2">Click Two</button>
<button onclick="buttonClicked(this)" data-tracking="3">Click Three</button>
```

Comment: Hi everyone, 

Thank you all for your suggestion. 

This is the end result: 

<button id="Call Label Here">Call Label Here</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var button = document.getElementById('Call Label Here');
  button.addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function() { 
      fbq('track', 'click to call', {
        tracking_number: 'phone_number_here',
      });          
    },
    false
  );
</script>